# Scenic view source code?

Tags: javafx, scenic

Where can i find the source code for the scenic view application of JavaFX. 

Is it even Open Source.? Unzipping the jar provides cryptic classes which are difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google search I found the code here: https://bitbucket.org/scenicview/scenic-view/src